# NHibernate Unit test fails with Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mocking

My test is setup with mocking data like this

```
var persons = new List<Core.Domain.Person>
{
    new Core.Domain.Person { DisplayName = "Coordinator 1", Email="coordinator01@wur.nl", WurAccount = "coord001" },
    new Core.Domain.Person { DisplayName = "Coordinator 2", Email="coordinator02@wur.nl", WurAccount = "coord002" }
};

this.mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Query<Core.Domain.Person>()).Returns(persons.AsQueryable);
```

In the code to test the persons are retrieved like this

```
private Dictionary<string, Domain.Person> GetPersons(IEnumerable<string> wurAccounts)
{
    var accounts = wurAccounts.ToList();
    return this.session.Query<Domain.Person>()
        .Where(x => accounts.Contains(x.WurAccount))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.WurAccount);
}
```

When I run the test I get a NullReferenceException here:

```
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector)
   at Wur.P2G.Core.Services.PersonSynchronizer.GetPersons(IEnumerable`1 wurAccounts) in C:\Projects\P2G\P2G\Sources\Wur.P2G.Core\Services\PersonSynchronizer.cs:line 112
```

EDIT

I was able to boile it down to this piece of code that still causes the NullReference Exception:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Wur.P2G.Core.Services.Tests
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        ISession Session { get; }
        IQueryable<T> Query<T>();
        void BeginTransaction();
        void Commit();
        void Rollback();
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public virtual string WurAccount { get; set; }
        public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual bool HasValidEmail => true;
        public override string ToString() => WurAccount;
    }

    [TestClass()]
    public class PersonSynchronizerTests
    {
        private Mock<IUnitOfWork> mockUnitOfWork;
        private Mock<ISession> mockSession;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            this.mockSession = new Mock<ISession>();
            this.mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(this.mockSession.Object);
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void GetPersonsTest()
        {
            var persons = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { DisplayName = "Coordinator 1", Email="coordinator01@wur.nl", WurAccount = "coord001" },
                new Person { DisplayName = "Coordinator 2", Email="coordinator02@wur.nl", WurAccount = "coord002" }
            };

            this.mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.Query<Person>()).Returns(persons.AsQueryable);

            var wurAccounts = new[] { "coord001", "coord002" };

            var accounts = wurAccounts.ToList();
            var personsRead = mockSession.Object.Query<Person>()
                .Where(x => accounts.Contains(x.WurAccount))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.WurAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

Some more text because the stupid editor want it from me.

Comment: For what it's worth. I've determined that it happens during Enumeration in the ToDictionary(). Leaving out the Where() does not make a difference

Comment: Is this a typo? `.Returns(persons.AsQueryable);` or did you mean to call the actual extension method there? Really can't provide much help with out a complete picture of the problem. And with what is provided we are left guessing. which is a waste of all our time.

Comment: I don't think it's a typo. What you should know that this is an older test that ran for many years. It could be connected to a breaking change of some sort. Don't want to waste your time. Creating a working sample would probably help understand but I a daunting task and will take a lot of effort and time

Comment: While the error message shows that the problem is related to `NHibernate.Linq`, None of the code shown so far is related to `NHibernate` unless there is something you are not showing that is using it.

Answer (score 1):

While the error message shows that the problem is related to `NHibernate.Linq`, None of the code shown so far is related to `NHibernate` unless there is something you are not showing that is using it.

The code shown so far should work as expected as demonstrated by the following minimal, complete and verifiable example based on the original example provided.

```
[TestClass]
public class PersonSynchronizerTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void PersonSynchronizer_GetPerson_Should_Return_Two() {
        //Arrange
        var wurAccounts = new[] { "coord001", "coord002" };
        var persons = new List<Person> {
            new Person { DisplayName = "Coordinator 1", Email="coordinator01@wur.nl", WurAccount = wurAccounts[0] },
            new Person { DisplayName = "Coordinator 2", Email="coordinator02@wur.nl", WurAccount = wurAccounts[1] }
        };

        var mockSession = new Mock<ISession>();
        mockSession.Setup(_ => _.Query<Person>()).Returns(persons.AsQueryable); //<-- setup session

        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(_ => _.Query<Person>()).Returns(persons.AsQueryable);
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(_ => _.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object); //<-- UoW returns session

        var subject = new PersonSynchronizer(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        //Act
        var actual = subject.GetPersons(wurAccounts);

        //Assert
        actual.Should()
            .NotBeNull()
            .And.HaveCount(wurAccounts.Length);
    }

    public class PersonSynchronizer {
        private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private ISession session;

        public PersonSynchronizer(IUnitOfWork uow) {
            this.unitOfWork = uow;
            this.session = unitOfWork.Session;
        }
        public Dictionary<string, Person> GetPersons(IEnumerable<string> wurAccounts) {
            var accounts = wurAccounts.ToList();
            return this.session.Query<Person>()
                .Where(x => accounts.Contains(x.WurAccount))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.WurAccount);
        }
    }

    public class Person {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string WurAccount { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable {
        ISession Session { get; }
        IQueryable<T> Query<T>();
        void BeginTransaction();
        void Commit();
        void Rollback();
    }

    public interface ISession {
        IQueryable<T> Query<T>();
    }
}
```

The snippet above passes as expected when tested.

I suggest reviewing if there are any NHibernate extension methods being called that may be conflicting with the default Linq Extensions, causing the issues encountered.

Comment: Wow, thanks Nkosi. I'll take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine too. I've edited the original post and added an example that boils down to the error.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. The mockUnitOfWork has the setup for the Query but the Query runs on the mochSession. Changing mockSession.Object.Query<Person>(); to mockUnitOfWork.Object.Query<Person>(); solves the NullReferenceException.

Comment: So the problem now is. How do I change the test so it setup the mockSession correctly.

Comment: @PaulSinnema I had made assumptions based on the code you showed. which boiled down to a guess. In your edit you did not do any setup on the session so it null out when invoking its members. Also I assumed `Query` is an instance member and not an extension method. I say this because of Query` is in fact an extension method Moq can't work with extension methods.